# Antlr 4 - Java grammar rule "Explicit Generic Invocation" never gets visited

Tags: antlr, antlr4, code-translation

I was building a listener to translate all java method calls A.Foo(args) to A.Bar(args). It appeared to me that the rule:

```
expression '.' explicitGenericInvocation
```

Is the most fitting rule to listen to. However, after visual inspection of the tree, I realized that all java method calls are recognized as the rule

```
expression '(' expressionList? ')'
```

whereas the expression term is further matched to

```
expression '.' Identifier
```

It seems that the expression rule overrides the explicitGenericInvocation rule all the time. Is this intended or is there a flaw in the java grammar? If it is intended, then what is the correct interpretation of the rule explicitGenericInvocation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

explicitGenericInvocation must start with nonWildcardTypeArguments which is <...>. a.Foo(args) therefore matches the  general rule instead of the specialized one for generic types.